# Passing Returned Data from a PHP Script into a Highcharts data[] block?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, object, highcharts

I have a Highchart scatter chart that plots data calculated using a PHP script. Values are passed to the PHP script via the jQuery .get function and returned to an ExpressionEngine template. The PHP code I'm using is like so:

```
    printf("{x:'%3.2f',y:'%3.2f',fillColor:'#058DC7'},",$annualReturns[2] * 100.0,$annualSemiStDev[2]);
    printf("{x:'%3.2f',y:'%3.2f',fillColor:'#50B432'},",$annualReturns[3] * 100.0,$annualSemiStDev[3]);
    printf("{x:'%3.2f',y:'%3.2f',fillColor:'#ED561B'},",$annualReturns[4] * 100.0,$annualSemiStDev[4]);
```

Once back in the ExpressionEngine template, the data is immediately shuffled off to the Highcharts library through a JavaScript function (some of the data going into the PHP script is compiled by another JavaScript function) which creates the Highcharts scatter plot.

```
    updateScatterChart(data);
```

This is where I'm running into my issue. The data needs to render, as expected here:

```
  series: [{
          name: 'Custom',
          data:[ DATA NEEDS TO LIVE HERE ]
          }]
```

To confirm I'm getting the right data, immediately inside the updateScatterChart function, I'm displaying the results in an alert window -- using `alert(data)` -- and I get this:

```
  {x:'12.48',y:'3.52',fillColor:'#058DC7'}
  {x:'34.82',y:'16.11',fillColor:'#50B432'}
  {x:'8.32',y:'9.35',fillColor:'#ED561B'}
```

which, when pasted inside my `data[]` block my scatter chart renders as expected. So, my data is good. That pasted code block looks like this:

```
  series: [{
          name: 'Custom',
          data:[ 
               {x:'12.48',y:'3.52',fillColor:'#058DC7'}
               {x:'34.82',y:'16.11',fillColor:'#50B432'}
               {x:'8.32',y:'9.35',fillColor:'#ED561B'}
              ]
          }]
```

The connection point I'm missing is getting that returned data to output directly into the `data:[]` block.

I'm fairly new to PHP and less so to JavaScript, but switching languages like this (moving data from PHP to JavaScript) is still a bit beyond my knowledge base.

Comment: 'The connection point I'm missing is getting that returned data to output directly into the data:[] block without.'

Sorry, without what?

Comment: Ah, without was leftover from an earlier draft. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        (object)array('x'=>12.48, 'y'=>3.52, 'fillOClor'=>'#058DC7'),
        (object)array('x'=>34.82, 'y'=>16.11, 'fillOClor'=>'#50B432'),
        //more to come
    );
?>
series: [{
      name: 'Custom',
      data: <?php echo json_encode($data)?>
      }]
```

Note square brackets are removed from `data`

Comment: I'll give this one a shot in a little bit, it looks promising.